# how to return only the value contained in the field without the key with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**friends i have the following query in mongoose:**

```
return this.connection
      .find({ texts: { $in: textIds }})
      .select('texts -_id');
```

**and this returns me**

```
[{text: 'aaa'}, {text: 'bbb'}]
```

**is there any way for this query to return the data to me without the key as follows:**

```
['aaa','bbb']
```

I didn't find anything that could help me here on the stack, maybe I've searched the wrong way, but could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

```
this.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "values": {
        "$push": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$in": [
                "$texts",
                textIds
              ]
            },
            "$text",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```